# C++ Feature test macros and getting rid of preprocessor in my own code

Tags: c++, preprocessor, c++17

I have a design question. In C++ there are feature test recommendation macros: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/feature_test

In the explanation from the link above, I cite textually:

> The following macros expand to a numeric value corresponding to the year and month when the feature has been included in the working draft. When a feature changes significantly, the macro will be updated accordingly.

I would like to make use of these feature test macros to simplify the build system and at the same time to get rid of the preprocessor in my own code

My questions are:

1. Given a `__cpp_feature_xyz`, it is defined with a numeric value, if it exists, but, if it does not exist, is it `#define`d at all? This would make possible to use inside `if constexpr`
2. When modules come out, these macros are supposed to be compatible no matter what happens with macro propagation? Some of these macros seem to be built-in, but for the library features it seems that you need to include the corresponding header, so I wonder if they would be propagated or an option to do so. I am aware this is one of the controversial design points of modules.
3. If macro propagation is finally removed from modules, are there any planned replacement mechanisms for feature detection?

Comment: It is impossible to use these feature test macros without employing the preprocessor.

Comment: I do not understand why people in the committee or just Bjarne Stroustrup say the preprocessor is a headache just to do the opposite when they add this kind of mechanism... Is there any backwards-compatibility requirement for this? Or they just chose macros for inertia? Or it is just a lack of alternative mechanisms that are more effective?

Comment: @Peter why `__cpp_feature_xyz` cannot be used in `if constexpr`. Is the reason that it is not guaranteed to be `#define`d?

Comment: Generally speaking, all a macro `__cpp_feature_xyz` gives is a way of testing if an implementation (or the implementer) *claims* to support a feature.    The preprocessor does text substitution in source code - the text substituted by the macro will determine if it can be used in `if constexpr`.    Bear in mind that support of `constexpr` is one of the features that can be tested for - if the macro is not defined, use of `if constexpr` would be invalid anyway.